# How to plot a Pandas dataframe by filtering a column

Tags: python, pandas, plot, histogram

I have the following Pandas `df`:

[image: Pandas dataframe]

And I want to generate seven different histogram plots according to the weekday to show the attendance to a place in each hour of the day.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried to do it and what was a problem?

Comment: I want to know how can I generate a plot for Sunday, Monday, and so on... in the x label should be the hour and in the y label the visit_weight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example for the weekday friday:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(x = 'at_what_time', height = 'visit_weight', data = df[df['weekday']=='friday'])
```